# I can't destroy or place blocks in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing minecraft single player and every time I try to destroy or place blocks in every world and game mode it always comes up with the chat control instead.I tried restarting it and creating new worlds but nothing seems to be working. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the options menu and re-bind your controls. Seems like you have somehow bound the mouse button to the open chat dialog.